# How to pass parameters to an alias?

Tags: shell, alias, parameter

For bash script, I can use `"$@"` to access arguments. What's the equivalent when I use an alias?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Aliases are like commands in that all arguments to them are passed as arguments to the program they alias. For instance:

```bash
alias ls='ls -l -a -t -r'
# This now executes 'ls -l -a -t -r foo bar'
ls foo bar
```

If you want to have actual control over how the arguments are interpreted, then you could write a function like so:

```bash
my_program_wrapper() {
    local first_arg=$1 \
          second_arg=$2

    shift 2 # get rid of the first two arguments

    # ...

    /path/to/my_program "$@"
}
```

Comment: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05 Functions in `sh` are defined `my_program_wrapper() { ...; }`.  Bash does handle the keyword `function` but why not go with what's more portable?

Comment: Do you have to export the function for it to be available as an interactive shell executable?

Comment: @SridharSarnobat If by export you mean `export -f my_program_wrapper` [see this question for an explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22796/1655), then the answer is no; you will want to add the function to `~/.bashrc` in order to have it usable in interactive shells.

Answer (score 113):

**Alias solution**

If you're really against using a function per se, you can use:

```
$ alias wrap_args='f(){ echo before "$@" after;  unset -f f; }; f'
$ wrap_args x y z
before x y z after
```

You can replace `$@` with `$1` if you only want the first argument.

**Explanation**

This creates a temporary function `f`, which is passed the arguments.

Alias arguments are only passed at the end. Note that `f` is called at the very end of the alias.

The `unset -f` removes the function definition as the alias is executed so it doesn't hang around afterwards.

Comment: This is great for special cases. Consider a block of code where you want to prevent echo with minimal fuss: `alias echo='f(){ echo "$@" &>/dev/null; unset -f f; }; f'`. For example, adding that one line to a boot script to force a quiet mode.

Comment: This looks like a useless complication that still has many of the downsides of an alias, like the quoting hell that comes up if the function code itself needs to use single-quoted strings. Just defining the function the usual way wouldn't suffer that problem, and `wrap_args(){ echo before "$@" after; };` would be shorter to boot, _and_ there wouldn't be name clashes with the temporary function...

Comment: Is this a correct way to resolve that problem? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/742098/129967

Answer (score 29):

Adding to the present answers, an important thing to realize about how aliases work is that all the parameters you type after an aliased command will be used literally at the end. So there is no way to use alias for two commands (piped or not), out of which the first should interpret the parameters. To make it clear, here's an example of something that would not work as expected:

```
alias lsswp="ls -l | grep swp"
```

(an example inspired by [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19926/aliases-interpretation)) this will always use the output of `ls -l` performed in the *current* directory and do a grep on that - so using

```
lsswp /tmp/
```

would be equivalent to `ls -l | grep swp /tmp/`  and **not** `ls -l /tmp/ | grep swp`.

For all purposes where the arguments should be used somewhere in the middle, one needs to use a *function* instead of an alias.

Comment: plus one, `alias lsswp='ls -l | grep swp'` with single quote is also working on unix.

Answer (score 20):

You don't have to do anything, actually; aliases do this automatically.  For instance:

```
$ alias less="less -eirqM"
$ less foo.txt
```

You will see foo.txt's first page, and `less` will quit at EOF (-e), searches will be case-insensitive (-i), etc.

Comment: Can you please look at [my question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248080/how-to-create-an-alias-for-two-git-commands-that-use-a-parameter) - **none of the solutions works for me** and I am not allowed start a bounty.

Comment: @JJD The one who answered your question is correct: you want a function in that case, not an alias. Since the accepted answer to *this* question is essentially the same, your question was rightly closed.

Answer (score 6):

I'm answering for csh:

Yes, you can use the parameters in aliases and - as a difference to what has been said above - you can refer to them anywhere in the definition of alias - not only at the end.

Example for tar-gz -ing something:

```
$ alias tgz "tar cvf - \!:1 | gzip -9 > \!:2.tar.gz"
```

, where `!:1` and `!:2` are the parameters you will supply when calling your alias.

Example of use:

```
    $ ls
    clrcf.dat                             user_comment_2016.06.03_12:51:50.txt  user_comment_2016.06.03_12:54:48.txt
        TEST-wADM.tec                         user_comment_2016.06.03_12:52:04.txt  user_comment_2016.06.03_12:55:13.txt


    $ tgz user* out
    a user_comment_2016.06.03_12:51:50.txt 1K
a user_comment_2016.06.03_12:52:04.txt 1K
a user_comment_2016.06.03_12:54:48.txt 1K
a user_comment_2016.06.03_12:55:13.txt 1K

    $ ls out*
    out.tar.gz
```

Which effectively means that you used two parameters that you inserted at arbitrary places of the tar command, making of all of it an alias `tgz`

Comment: I used to use csh exclusively, but since bash was always default I had to gave up and use bash..   This is one of the features from csh that I miss,  I was struggling to reproduce it in bash.   I guess there is no direct equivalent in bash, and that the best (only) alternative is to use a function.

Answer (score 2):

This example, to pretty print a markdown file in the terminal, is working if the first command of the pipe is able to read from stdin:

```
alias mdcat='(pandoc | lynx -stdin -dump) <'
```

So `mdcat myfile.md` can then be used instead of `pandoc myfile.md | lynx -stdin -dump`.

This is not exactly answering your question, as it does not make "$@" available in the alias, but it probably answers some real-world usecases for this question.

Comment: The (almost) equivalent function definition, `mdcat() (pandoc < "$1" | lynx -stdin -dump)`, would still be (barely) shorter. Though one probably would use `mdcat() { pandoc < "$1" | lynx -stdin -dump; }` anyway, as the subshell is unnecessary. Though in the case of the alias, the whole pipeline wouldn't start if one neglected to give the filename (as the plain `<` at end of line would be a syntax error), but the function would still start `lynx` on the right-hand side of the pipeline, even if the redirection on the left side failed. So in a way, that might be seen an advantage for the alias.