# Aliases interpretation

Tags: alias

I have a few aliases in `.bash_aliases`. I defined `c` alias as follows, but it does not work as it should:

```
...
alias cd='cd; ls -r --time=atime'
alias c='cd'
...
```

In `.bashrc` there is a line:

```
alias ls='clear; ls --color=auto'
```

Commnand `c` gives bad output now. It should give the same output as
`cd; clear; ls -r --time=atime --color=auto`.

Other problem: When I type `cd dir` I should stay in `dir` but I'm in `$HOME` as a result.

How can I solve this and improve in defining aliases? Is `.bash_aliases` interpreted as a `regular grammar`?

Comment: Define "bad output".  What does it do, and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: see question edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use functions instead, the advantage being the possibility to pass parameters and a cleaner syntax.

```
function cd() {
  command cd "$@"
  ls -r --time=atime
}

function c() {
 cd "$@"
}

function ls() {
  clear
  command ls --color=auto "$@"
}
```

(`command` is a `bash` builtin used to refer to the real command, and not functions with the same name).

Comment: `command cd` will give you `command not found: cd`, you meant `builtin cd`.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: are you sure? it works here

Comment: Seems that `bash` strangely accepts it. `zsh` doesn't… and `dash` don't know about `builtin`… what a mess.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez The [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/command.html) utility suppresses alias and function lookup only. It also has an effect on special built-ins (see the spec for details). `command cd` should always run the build-in. Zsh is non-standard by default, you need to set the `posix_builtins` option to make it behave according to the standard.

Answer (score 4):

`c` should be exactly equivalent to `cd`. I expect you'll see the same error from `cd dir` as from `c dir`, and that `c` alone works.

`cd` won't work the way you've defined it, because aliases perform a simple text substitution. `cd dir` is expanded to `cd; ls -r --time=atime dir`. Aliases are pretty much limited to giving a command a shorter name or providing default options, e.g. `alias c=cd` or `alias cp='cp -i'`. For anything more complex, such as running several commands, use a function.

```
cd () {
  command cd "$@" &&
  ls -r --time=atime
}
```

See also [Aliases vs functions vs scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4023/bash-functions-vs-scripts), [How to pass parameters to an alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameter-to-alias).

Comment: Thank you. You're right `c` and `cd` makes no difference. I will accept enzotib answer because it's larger, but your answer gives me the feeling of understanding and the ability to accept his answer. So it belongs to accepted too.