# How to write an alias function to make dd show progress bar?

Tags: bash, shell-script, dd, bash-script, bashrc

According to [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-dd-command-show-progress-while-coping/), by replacing:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb [additional options]
```

with:

```
$ pv -tpreb /dev/sda | dd of=/dev/sdb [additional options]
```

one can augment the default `dd` behaviour by displaying a progress bar, similar to that in `wget`. This works well when I can remember to use it, so I thought aliasing the first command to the second was the logical next step.

After some research, it would appear a simple `alias` in `.bash_rc` can't accomplish this. Could someone provide a BASH function to capture the `if=...` and work it into the resultant command?

Comment: Why not `pv < /dev/sda > /dev/sdb`. Beware of the implications of using `dd` with pipes.

Comment: Beside of this, `dd` use `USR1` signal to display progress statistics.

Answer (score 3):

Aliases are only suitable to give a command a shorter name or give it extra arguments. For anything else, use a function. See
[Aliases vs functions vs scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4023/aliases-vs-functions-vs-scripts) for more details.

```
pvdd () {
  pv -tpreb "$1" | dd of="$2"
}
pvdd /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

However, do not use this function. `dd if=foo of=bar` is equivalent to `cat <foo >bar`, only

- [slower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492), and worse,
- [unreliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial) in certain circumstances, especially when reading or writing to a pipe.

The use of `dd` as a low-level command to access disks is a myth¹. The magic comes from the `/dev` entries, not from `dd`.

So the command you want is simply

```
pv -tpreb /dev/sda >/dev/sdb
```

and you can make an alias for `dd -tpreb` if you like.

¹  <sub>There is a historical origin to this myth: when accessing tapes, the control over block size that `dd` provides is sometimes necessary. But for everything else, imposing a block size the way `dd` does it can lead to data loss.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't terribly clear, but it appears that you need a shell function.  You could create a function `mydd`:

```
mydd() { pv -tpreb /dev/sda | dd "$@"; }
```

and invoke it by saying:

```
mydd of=/dev/sdb [additional options]
```

and the executed command would be:

```
pv -tpreb /dev/sda | dd of=/dev/sdb [additional options]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's pretty close to where I need it, except `/dev/sda` should be a variable. Is it possible to make the shell function execute `pv -tpreb [source] | dd of=[dest] [optional additional options]` from `dd if=[source] of=[dest] [optional additional options]`? Thanks!