# How do I make "$@" insert an argument in the middle of a command?

Tags: bash, variable, alias

I'm trying to insert an argument in the middle of a command with `"$@"` for learning purposes. I don't know if that's optimal, but it's what I've been trying to do. This is what I have: when I run `test.sh foo` it runs `echo "$@" bar` which I was hoping would print `foo bar`. Instead, it's printing `bar foo`. I don't know neither if that's expected behavior nor what I should do instead.

```
test.sh foo
# runs
echo "$@" bar
# which is printing
bar foo
```

**Edit:** I had simplified the context and was in reality trying to use `"$@"` **in an alias.**

Comment: What does `test.sh` actually contain? If it really contained `echo "$@" bar`, the output of running `./test.sh foo` would be `foo bar`. Note that `test.sh foo` doesn't look for `test.sh` in the current directory unless you've added `.` to `PATH`. Maybe you have another `test.sh` somewhere else and you're running that?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Okay, so I'll be more specific. If I'm setting up an alias `test='echo "$@" bar'` and I run `test foo` in a terminal, it prints `bar foo`.

Comment: [Aliases vs functions vs scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4023/170373)

Comment: Aliases don't take arguments into `$@`, just whatever you stick after the alias name ends up at after the expansion, so you end up with `echo "$@" bar foo`.

Comment: @ilkkachu I see. So, asking as a newbie, a function would be an ideal alternative to what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are just a simple replacement, they don't take arguments themselves.
So if you have `alias x='echo "$@" bar'`<sup>(*)</sup>, and you run `x foo`, you end up with

```
echo "$@" bar foo
```

i.e. with just the alias name `x` replaced with the contents and the rest left on in the end. Now, **that `"$@"` is the argument list of the context where `x foo` was run**. Probably your interactive shell, which usually doesn't have anything in the argument list, so the `"$@"` gets removed. But if you had something in the argument list (positional parameters), they'd be expanded at that position:

```
$ alias x='echo "$@" bar'
$ set -- args here
$ x foo
args here bar foo
```

Instead, if you used a function or a script file, that would work. This should print `foo bar`:

```
f() {
    echo "$@" bar
}
f foo
```

as should running something like `./s.sh foo`, if `s.sh` is executable and contains that `echo` line.

See:

- [Aliases vs functions vs scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4023/170373)
- [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)
- [How to pass parameters to an alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3773/170373)
- [Bash reference: 6.6 Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html)

<sub>(* `test` is a standard command, the same as `[ .. ]`, so better not use it for... well, this kind of testing purposes.)</sub>