# Error creating an alias for the find command

Tags: find, alias

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass parameter to alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameter-to-alias)

I am trying to shorten the `find` command, but getting an error:

```
$ alias f='find . -name $1 -print'
$ f JobConf.java
```

> find: paths must precede expression: JobConf.java
>   Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliases are just simple replacements and don't work that way.  You probably want a function, which do everything aliases can do and more.

```
f () { find . -name "$1" -print; }
```