# Can I "export" functions in bash?

Tags: bash, function

```
source some_file
```

some_file:

```
doit ()
{
  echo doit $1
}
export TEST=true
```

If I source **some_file** the function "doit" and the variable TEST are available on the command line. But running this script:

script.sh:

```
#/bin/sh
echo $TEST
doit test2
```

Will return the value of TEST, but will generate an error about the unknown function "doit".

Can I "export" the function, too, or do I have to source some_file in script.sh to use the function there?

Comment: summarizing answers below (enzotib is correct, assuming you can use bash, as the question indicates): change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` and _after_ `doit() {...}` just `export -f doit`

Comment: Just for the record: This solution will usually work when you use `#!/bin/sh` too, but it is good practice to use `#!/bin/bash` so that you avoid problems when the default shell is not bash.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885871/exporting-a-function-in-shell

Comment: @Nagel 
`sh: 1: export: Illegal option -f`

Answer (score 241, accepted):

In Bash you can export function definitions to other shell scripts that your script calls with

```
export -f function_name
```

For example you can try this simple example:

#### `./script1`:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfun() {
    echo "Hello!"
}

export -f myfun
./script2
```

#### `./script2`:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfun
```

Then if you call `./script1` you will see the output *Hello!*.

Comment: To clarify, for those who are wondering: it does _not_ work with zsh (according to my testing). It also only works from bash -> bash, not bash -> zsh.

Answer (score 35):

"Exporting" a function using `export -f` creates an environment variable with the function body. Consider this example:

```
$ fn(){ echo \'\"\ \ \$; }
$ export -f fn
$ sh -c printenv\ fn
() {  echo \'\"\ \ \$
}
```

This means that only the shell (just Bash?) will be able to accept the function. You could also set the function yourself as the Bash only considers envvars starting with `() {` as function:

```
$ fn2='() { echo Hi;}' sh -c fn2
Hi
$ fn3='() {' sh -c :
sh: fn3: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: error importing function definition for `fn3'
```

If you need to "export" this variable over SSH, then you really need the function as a string. This can be done with the print option (`-p`) for functions (`-f`) of the `declare` built-in:

```
$ declare -pf fn
fn () 
{ 
    echo \'\"\ \ \$
}
```

This is very useful if you have more complex code that needs to be executed over SSH. Consider the following fictitious script:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_main() {
   local dest="$HOME/destination"

   tar xzv -C "$dest"
   chgrp -R www-data "$dest"
   # Ensure that newly written files have the 'www-data' group too
   find "$dest" -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
}
tar cz files/ | ssh user@host "$(declare -pf remote_main); remote_main"
```

Comment: `fn2='() { echo Hi;}' sh -c fn2` did not work for me. On arch linux with `sh` being bash v5.0.7 I got `sh: fn2: command not found`. On Ubuntu with with `sh` being dash v0.2.3 I got `sh: 1: fn2: not found`. Which `sh` shell did you use?

Comment: I think your answer is wrong. `f(){ echo a;}; export -f f; echo "$f"; sh -c 'printenv f; echo "$f"'` prints nothing for me, so clearly `f` isn't exported as a plain string. I tested with both combinations mentioned above.

Comment: And even if the function was exported as a string, why should `sh` execute that string as a function? In your example `fn2='() { echo Hi;}' sh -c fn2` the command `fn2` given to `sh`  is literally the string `"fn2"`. `sh` should search for such a command in its PATH but should *not* look if there is a variable `$fn2`, expand that variable, and execute its value as a function – sounds like a major security issue to me. **edit:** I think that's it! Was your shown behavior the security bug known as [ShellShock/Bashdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug))?

Comment: With Bash 5.0.7 (Arch Linux), it appears that a prefix is prepended. This was likely done in response to ShellShock. Example: `fn(){ echo foo; }; export -f fn; env | grep foo` outputs `BASH_FUNC_fn%%=() {  echo foo`

Answer (score 13):

Building on [@Lekensteyn's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148748/83904)...

If you use `declare -pf` it will output all the previously defined functions in the current shell to STDOUT.

At that point you can redirect STDOUT to wherever you want and in effect stuff the previously defined functions wherever you want.

The following answer will stuff them into a variable. Then we echo that variable plus the invocation of the function that we want to run into the new shell that is spawned as a new user. We do this by using `sudo` with the `-u` (aka. `user`) switch and simply running Bash (which will receive the piped STDOUT as the input to run).

As we know that we are going from a Bash shell to a Bash shell we know that Bash will interpret the previous shells defined functions correctly. The syntax should be fine as long as we are moving between one Bash shell of the same version to a new Bash shell of the same version.

YMMV if you are moving between different shells or between systems that may have different versions of Bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
  echo "hello from `whoami`"
}

FUNCTIONS=`declare -pf`; echo "$FUNCTIONS ; foo" | sudo -u otheruser bash
# $./test.sh
# hello from otheruser
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot export functions, not in the way that you are describing.  The shell will only load the `~/.bashrc` file on the start of an interactive shell (search for "Invocation" in the [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)).

What you can do is create "library" which is loaded when you start the program:

```
source "$HOME/lib/somefile"
```

And place your non-interactive functions and settings there.

Comment: So I have to either start the subshell with the "login" parameter (to parse ~/.profile) or source that file.

Comment: Looking a little more closely, on non-interactive shells, you could set `BASH_ENV` environment variable to `some_file` you already have, and it would be called.  It would be easy enough to find that out: `echo echo foobar > /tmp/foobar; BASH_ENV=/tmp/foobar $SHELL -c :`

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. I've written plenty of shell scripts, including library scripts. For some reason, even though my `.profile` is successfully sourcing my `.bashrc` (I tested by echoing a variable that would have been sourced). I just can't figure out why it can't find my function, but it can find a var to echo.

Comment: I realize it's been a long time, but this is a VERY useful way to load all your functions into the shell, and then execute them as needed for your main script. In a long script, sometimes you run into issues where one function must be loaded before another (you get "[script name:] line [number:] [function name:] command not found",  but in the "library" it doesn't matter what order they are in.

Comment: You seem to be saying that `export -f` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

`eval "$(declare -F | sed -e 's/-f /-fx /')"` will export **all** functions.

I do this a lot before starting an interactive shell in a script to enable me to debug and work in the script context while using its functions and variables.

Example:

```
eval "$(declare -F | sed -e 's/-f /-fx /')"
export SOME IMPORTANT VARIABLES AND PASSWORDS
bash -i
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions are not exported to subprocesses. This is why there are files named .kshrc or .bashrc: To define functions that shoiuld be available in subshells also.

If running a script, the .*shrc scripts are normally not sourced. You would have to code that explicitly, like in `. ~/.kshrc`.

Comment: So the ~root/.bashrc could be an option in my case, since the scripts are run as root. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: if using the .*shrc files, be sure they dont force interactive behaviour (like the stupid alias `rm=rm -i`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm new to Linux, but you can try this. In some file, let's call it, 'tmp/general' you build your function:

```
func1(){
   echo "func from general"
}
```

In your shell script add:

```
. /tmp/general
```

and run:

```
func1
```

You'll get on the screen: `func from general`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare -x -f NAME
```

More info

```
-f        restrict action or display to function names and definitions
-x        to make NAMEs export
```