# The command can't execute in vim environment

Tags: bash, vim, source

The `mycommand` is a function in my lib/work.sh file.

```
cat .bashrc
source /home/lib/work.sh
```

It means that `mycommand` was sourced in automatically.
`mycommand` can execute in terminal.
Now to edit a file with `vim test.txt`,`shift+"` to enter into vim's command mode ,input `!mycommand` ,

```
/bin/bash: mycommand: command not found

shell returned 127

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Why `mycommand` can't found in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of shells - [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)  (look for the `.bashrc` part)

Not all of them are sourcing `.bashrc` thus `work.sh` isn't sourced.

To solve your problem you need to export your function to make it available to a subshell.

[Can I "export" functions in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash#22867)

```
myfun() {
    echo "Hello!"
}

export -f myfun
```

--

```
vim
:!myfun
```

works!