# How to make my bash function known to external program

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, arguments

I have bash functions `foo` and `bar` in my `~/.bashrc`.

Function `foo` calls an external command `ext_command` that itself takes as one of its arguments another command. I want to pass `bar` as that command, i.e. I'd want my `.bashrc` to look something like this:

```
bar() {
...
}
foo() {
 ext_command --invoke bar
}
```

However, this doesn't work, because the external command, which is not a shell script, doesn't know `bar`. How can I solve this?

I was thinking to instead do

```
ext_command --invoke "bash -c 'bar'"
```

But the Bash in this invocation isn't run as an interactive shell, so it doesn't know `bar` either.

Hence, I believe one way to solve my problem would be to force Bash to be run as an interactive shell; unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Another way that I would have thought should definitely work is to use

```
ext_command --invoke "bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc; bar'"
```

but for some reason this doesn't work and indeed simply running

```
bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc; bar'
```

in an interactive bash session gives

```
bash: bar: command not found
```

In any case, I don't like that solution, because I'd like `foo` to work no matter which file it is sourced from.

Comment: Make a shellscript named `bar`.

Comment: @IporSircer I don't like the clutter. I am already using the same `~/.bashrc` on all the different machines I'm working on and don't want to have to install and update that additional script file on each.

Comment: What is `ext_command`? What does it use `bar` for? Can it be made to read the output from `bar` or in some other way do what it's supposed to do without injecting shell code into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally have these ways to go:

1. Rewrite the function to command, ie. a script on its own. A common practice is to keep a `~/bin` directory and include it in your `$PATH`.
2. Export the function to the environment and make the other shell get it from there. See [Can I "export" functions in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash)
3. Stick to `bar` being a sourcable function, but sourcing it from `~/.bashrc` may not be the best solution. You might put it in its own file in `~/bin` and source it from there. This would make things simple.
4. If possible, feed the logic to the `ext_command` in your `foo` function somehow else, eg. through a here-doc.

Comment: 2. works perfectly. I don't even understand what 'make the other shell get it from there' means and it still works. I'm simply using `ext_command --invoke bar`

Comment: @Bananach From there = from the environment.

Comment: Okay, but what is "the other shell" in your sentence? I'm perfectly happy, but just to be sure, is what I am doing now what you meant I should? If so, I simply don't understand in which way I am using "another shell"

Comment: @Bananach Check `ext_command`. It must invoke another Bash, is a Bash script itself, or is something unusual that can import Bash functions from the environment.

Comment: It's a binary, `fzf` to be precise, and what I call `invoke` here is actually `preview`. It does seem to invoke another bash because if I don't `export -f bar` it says   `/bin/bash: bar: command not found` in its preview window. I guess I lucked out then, since I didn't like any of the other options :)