# Unix alias with parameters

Tags: shell, alias

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass parameters to an alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias)

I'm wondering if it is possible to define an alias with parameters.

For example, when I have to compile a tex file I execute pdflatex and then I have to open the pdf:

```
$ pdlatex Main.tex
$ Open Main.pdf
```

Is there a way for defining an alias like this:

```
alias buildPdf="pdflatex x.tex && Open x.pdf"
```

Where x is a parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a function. Add to your `.bashrc` or simply copypasta into your terminal:

```
function buildPdf() {
  pdflatex "$1.tex" && Open "$1.pdf"
}
```

Comment: `$1` instead of `%1`, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, can I define it in the `.bashrc`?

Comment: @lucaghera, yes, or in `.profile`, depending on which file is sourced when you start your shell.

Comment: @Jan it returns me this error when I open the bash: `-bash: /Users/luca/.profile: line 35: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @lucaghera, try adding newlines, as in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

With bash this is not possible. Consider using a bash script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
pdflatex "$1".tex
Open "$1".pdf
```

- Call this 'buildPdf'
- give it executable permission (chmod +x)
- place it in a directory listed in $PATH

Voila!