# bashrc: alias vs function - difference calling cd in a multiple command

Tags: bash, shell-script

If I define an alias like this in .bashrc:

```
alias cd="cd $1 && ls"
```

If I call:

```
cd test
```

It correctly shows file in test directory but no changes the current directory.

If I define a function in .bashrc:

```
function cd {
 cd "$1" && ls
}
```

Now if i call

```
cd test
```

It correctly shows file in test directory and changes the current directory to "test".

Anyone knows what is the difference?

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3773/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29060/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453827/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29060/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50006/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27559/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366009/5132 and …

Comment: Most important: alias works by replacing one *string* with another *string*. There is no logic, only string replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in your first example of alias call you made after expansion:

```
cd test ---> cd $1 && ls test
```

It is the basic difference between the bash script call and the expansion of an alias! By use of an alias your parameter is written after all the characters of the alias definition. The `$1` is used literally and it is not substituted with the word `test` from the end. You can simply verify this by changing the order of commands in the alias definition

```
alias cd="ls $1 && cd"
```

gives you the correct change of the directory, but no directory list.

Comment: Very userful answer. Thanks!