# Bash alias arguments

Tags: bash, alias

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass parameters to an alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias)

I am trying to make a bash alias that will allow me to quickly make an archive of the current git repo.

My current alias is:

`alias gitarch="git archive master --format=tar | gzip >$@"`

This works great if I supply a destination file exactly like `gitarch ~/Desktop/MyArchive.tar.gz` but I want to be able to just type a filename and it will always save to the desktop with the tar.gz extension. I tried doing:

`alias gitarch="git archive master --format=tar | gzip >~/Desktop/$@.tar.gz"`

... but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Can anyone tell me the secret to getting this working?

Comment: To help a little bit more, if you say `alias sayhello='echo "sayhello $@ and something else"'` and then you type `sayhello Dario` it will show `sayhello  and something else Dario`. That is the problem of the $@ you used. You're creating a `.tar.gzYOURNAME` file, so that the file should be hidden =P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The secret is simply creating a `bash` function instead - aliases don't support positional parameter substitution:

```
gitarch() { git archive master --format=tar | gzip >"$1"; }
```

Comment: The only "thing" is that it will not be shown when you say just 'alias'

Comment: @D4RIO No problem, just use `set` to list the functions or `type`.

Comment: I would use `"$1"` instead of `$@`.

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to get it working with all your help. I'm not exactly sure why this is flagged as duplicate, the other possible question was nothing like mine.

Comment: @D4RIO you can always alias the function as `alias gita="gitarch"`. Not perfect but does make it show up.