# how to add parameter to bash alias without space in between?

Tags: bash, alias

We can do with ease:

```
myalias='command param1 param2'
```

then `myalias param3` runs

```
command param1 param2 param3
```

I need an alias which will run the same, but without the last 'space':

```
command param1 param2param3
```

For example I have many servers in /24 subnet and need to run the same command using the ip. So I want alias like `command param1 192.168.0.` then just run `myalias 103` and the command will be applied to 192.168.0.103.

I tried to add `$1` at the end of the alias but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, aliases are fairly limited. As the Bash docs state: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."

Comment: For anything even vaguely complicated, functions make much more sense. Aliases really are just aliases, i.e. renaming an existing command..

Comment: Related: [How to pass parameters to an alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias)

Comment: Do you have a non dummy example you could post because I'm not sure what practical purpose passing 2 parameters without the space actually serves?

Comment: @JoeHealey Added more details, hope it helps.

Comment: It is not duplicate, because as marked in @Warren Young answer on that question - "You don't have to do anything, actually" if you want just to pass a param. I needed to pass it in a quite special way. Nevertheless, one of those answers helped me.

Answer (score 14):

If you are happy to use a function, you can do something like:

```
command(){
"$1" "$2" "192.168.0.${3}"
}
```

If I test this with a dummy command:

```
mycommand(){
$1 "130.200.68.${2}"
}

$ mycommand ping 180
```

Would ping the server with the last section of the IP added.

Comment: Good idea! Would it there be a way to use also provide the autocompletion facility we get using alias?