# Creating alias with single parameter used in multiple places

Tags: alias

I am trying to create a simple alias for SSH-ing to a host, like the below:

```
alias wpessh='ssh $1@$1.ssh.wpengine.net'
```

I also tried using a function as suggested by other answers here:

```
function wpessh { ssh "$1"@"$1".ssh.wpengine.net; }
export -f wpessh
```

But neither has worked.

#### Input

```
wpessh mysite
```

#### Expected Output (expected command to be run)

```
ssh mysite@mysite.ssh.wpengine.net
```

Comment: What shell are you using? What happens if you add an echo for debugging purposes, i.e. `function wpessh { echo ssh "$1"@"$1".ssh.wpengine.net; }`

Comment: @Sparhawk I'm just using OSX terminal. If I echo the function as you describe, I receive the SSH `usage:[....]`

Comment: What's the `$1` contents when issuing the alias? What's the resulting command (try `set -x`)? Why the upper case `SSH` in the error msgs?

Comment: check this out  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias it may be helpful

Comment: @BlackCrystal I actually already looked through that thread and tried using a function as described in the answers, but I can't get it to work for me here.

Comment: did you see one of answers that used `$@` instead of `$1`?

Comment: I have no idea why you get that output. It works for me. What about `function foo { echo $1 $1 ; }`, then `foo bar`? (Also, again, which shell are you using?)

Comment: @Sparhawk I'm using whatever is default in OSX Terminal. Bash?

Comment: Try `echo $0`. (And the other suggestion I made.)

Comment: @Sparhawk Interestingly your `foo bar` function works for me. Also, `echo $0` returns `-bash`. Still can't see why my SSH function doesn't work though.

Comment: Cool, I was testing with bash anyway. Okay, at least we have something working. Can you keep adding bits to get the function closer and closer to my original function in the top comment? Then see when it fails?

Comment: @wickywills I executed the `function wpessh { echo ssh "$1"@"$1".ssh.wpengine.net; }` in my OSX Shell both in bash and zsh and it's working fine.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri I don't understand. I use that function, and all I get returned is the usage for the `ssh` command (a shorter version of what I receive when running `man ssh`). I.e. it doesn't actually run the SSH, but if I run the command myself, outside of the function, and replacing the `$1`'s with my domain, then it works fine.

Comment: @wickywills maybe `ssh` is *already* an alias on your machine; what does `alias ssh` say?

Comment: @UncleBilly `-bash: alias: ssh: not found`, so nope, not an alias.