# Creating an alias for the find command in Linux

Tags: find, alias

I have created the following alias in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias find='find . -type f -name'
```

This obviates the need to type `. -type f -name` every time I do a file search. However, I still have to enclose search strings with '*...*'. How could I include these in the alias, so that instead of having to type:

```
find '*string*'
```

I could just type,

```
find string
```

Comment: See [How to pass parameters to an alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias), [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy with an alias but you can just define a shell function instead.

```bsh
find() { /usr/bin/find . -type f -name "*$1*"; }
```