# Primitive Alias doesn't work in Bash

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

I wrote the following rather primitive alias:

```
alias unshorten="curl -k -v -I $1 2>&1 | grep -i '< location' | cut -d ' ' -f 3"
```

It's meant to unshorten the shortened link and then print out the real link without visiting the site itself. But when I try it out with a link it throws out this:

```
cut: 'https://testlinkhere.com': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't pass a parameter (`$1`) to a bash alias like that - see [How to pass parameters to an alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias)

Comment: you're trying to write a function. So write a function, not an alias.

Comment: How about `alias unshorten='curl -w "%{redirect_url}\n" -sIo /dev/null'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above I rewrote it into a function and it works wonders:

```
unshorten () {
curl -k -v -I  "$1" 2>&1 | grep -i '< location' | cut -d ' ' -f 3
}
```