# Quoting arguments for alias commands. How does that work?

Tags: bash, alias

I added alias for my git log command:

```
$ alias gl
alias gl='gn -c git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history'
$ alias gn
alias gn='git-number'
```

> -n flag of `git-number` command runs subcommand, like `sh -c` does.

And I noticed one strange thing. When I run:

```
gl -- lib/X.pm
```

It works like:

```
gn -c "git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history" -- lib/X.pm
```

But I expect this (not quotes at the end of string):

```
gn -c "git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history -- lib/X.pm"
```

Here is a full history of commands:

```
$ gl -- lib/X.pm
fatal: ambiguous argument 'lib/X.pm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ gn -c "git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history" -- lib/X.pm
fatal: ambiguous argument 'lib/X.pm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ gn -c "git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history -- lib/X.pm"
commit 9ce3e165f284d55503eff9b627ef3723854c53bb
...other expected output
```

**How to force `alias` to put together aliased options and new options?**

Comment: I suggest to use a function in `~/.bashrc`. See `help function`.

Comment: I think this is possible solution 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42466441/4632019

Comment: Definitely use a function.  Especially since the double quotes aren't even in your alias.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Why would the quotes appear there, and why would they appear _there_ specifically, and not at some position in the command line? After the alias is expanded, the command line is `gn -c git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history -- lib/X.pm`. And this is a case where the quotes, if there were any in the alias, would actually be there, as aliases are really just text replacement, unlike expansions.

Comment: Ditto. IMO the most important thing to understand about aliases is: aliases in Bash replace *text* with *text*, there is no logic, just text replacement.

Comment: What is `gn` and what does its `-c` option do? If we knew this, we would be able to help you by giving a shell function that does the right thing.

Comment: @Kusalananda: added description for gn

Comment: @ilkkachu, @KamilMaciorowski. I do not know why quotes are there, but it works like they are. Probably because the `--` is parsed in special way.

Comment: @EugenKonkov, the shell doesn't parse `--` in a special way. To see what it actually runs, you could 1) enable `set -x` and then run it, or 2) take the `args` script from  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and use that in the alias instead of `gn`. I'd suggest you do that and [edit] the question to show the results.

Comment: or e.g. just remove the `gn` alias, define a function `gn() { printf "<%s>" "$@"; echo; }` and then run the command with that `gl` alias. The output of `gl -- lib/X.pm` is then `<-c> <git> <log> <-w> <-b> <-p> <--ignore-blank-lines> <--full-history> <--> <lib/X.pm>` which clearly shows all those words as individual arguments, equally. Hence the alias didn't add any quotes.

Comment: then again, if it's just `gn` there treating `--` specially, then why not just add it in your alias in the correct place? (where ever that is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alias is a "dumb" replacement of a string by a text on the command line. An alias can not use arguments or do anything other than provide a text to replace the alias name. In your example, you want to take the argument(s) after the alias name and *insert* them into the command called by `git-number`.  Since the alias does not understand arguments, it can't do this.

Use a shell function. The below shell function assumes that `git-number -c` works precisely like `sh -c` would do with regards of providing arguments to the command(s) that the utility executes:

```bash
gl () {
    git-number -c 'git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history "$@"' gn "$@"
}
```

This shell function would call `git-number -c` with your `git log` command followed by the arbitrarily chosen string `gc` (which, if `git-number -c` behaves like `sh -c`, would be placed in `$0` in the shell that executes `git log`) and `"$@"`, the quoted arguments of the function.

The `git log` command would (again, provided `git-number -c` works just like `sh -c`) be called with the set arguments, followed by the arguments passed in by the shell function.

Calling this `gn` function with the two arguments `--` and `lib/X.pm` would end up calling `git log` (via `git-number -c`) with the extra arguments `--` followed by `lib/X.pm`.

```
gn -c "git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history -- -- lib/X.pm"
```

Since we are making an effort to pass the arguments correctly, this would also support passing arguments that contain spaces and newlines etc. This would not have been possible had we simply *injected* `$@` into the command called by `git-number -c` from the shell function.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with `git-number`. It cuts `--` from arguments. You idea that I should pass two arguments `--` saves me.